# php - preg_replace non-matched characters except matched strings

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have strings that like this :

```
// example
$str1 = "     10.503 GB  3.4 GiB   ";
$str2 = "  40.29 KiB    ";
$str3 = "14.3 GB    2.1 51   ";
```

Here is my regex, which match strings "10.503 GB", "3.4 GiB", "40.29 KiB" and "14.3 GB" respectively

```
$regex = '/(\d+\.\d+ [A-Za-z]+[^\s])/';
preg_match_all($regex, $str1, $out1);
preg_match_all($regex, $str2, $out2);
preg_match_all($regex, $str3, $out3);
```

So the problem is, how can I replace non matching characters that doesn't matched my regex pattern with user-defined character? Example is below :

```
$char = 'A'; // assume this is user input
$str1 = "     10.503 GB  3.4 GiB   ";
$str2 = "  40.29 KiB    ";
$str3 = "14.3 GB    2.1 51   ";

/* preg_replace (or another preg_* magic here */
```

so the last strings will be

```
$str1 = "AAAAA10.503 GBAA3.4 GiBAAA";
$str2 = "AA40.29 KiBAAAA";
$str3 = "14.3 GBAAAAAAAAAAAAA";
```

I know the solutions without using preg_replace, but just pretend that preg_replace is necessity here (or another preg_* if you prefer)

So it's possible? and if it's, how can I accomplish that?

Comment: If not PHP, what engine do you also need to support? I guess this question is answered. Only Boost can do this job correctly with a conditional replacement pattern, others will yield non-precise output (with one extra `A` after each non-match). Have a look at another [PHP regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dO5aX0/2).

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte has gave a perfect answer to my problem :) also thanks stribizhev for info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
~\d+\.\d+ [a-zA-Z]+\b(*SKIP)(*F)|.~
```

with A as replacement.

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/cA6iQ3/1)

`(*SKIP)` forces to not retry previously matched positions when the pattern fails after. `(*F)` or `(*FAIL)` forces the pattern to fail.

Note that to handle values without decimals, you should replace `\d+\.\d+` with `\d+(?:\.\d+)?`

---

If you doesn't use a regex engine with these backtracking control verbs (only available with Perl, language that uses PCRE, or the new Python regex module), you can achieve the same with a capture group and a backreference:

```
pattern: ((?:\d+(?:\.\d+)? [a-zA-Z]+\b)*).
replacement: \1A
or: $1A
```

With PCRE, Perl, the Python regex module and Ruby 2, you can also do that:

```
pattern: (?:\d+(?:\.\d+)? [a-zA-Z]+\b)*\K.
replacement: A
```

Comment: Wow! I totally surprised when I saw (*SKIP) and (*FAIL)! but throughout my further reading, this is only works in a PCRE engine which PHP relied so, but how can I accomplish this without depending on this feature? (example using another regex engines) *sorry for asking another question here*

Comment: @MohdShahril: I added a way without backtracking control verbs, but keep in mind that *the general regex pattern* doesn't exist, each language may have its own regex engine, implementation and syntax.

Comment: i see, but your general regex solution have a gap space between A's, it's un-avoidable? [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/cA6iQ3/2)

Comment: @MohdShahril: there are no gap spaces, it's only how regex101 displays the results. (a little strange indeed).

Comment: I see, sorry for that :( by the way, your answer is perfect! Looks like it gonna feel my whole gap today learning more how your regexes works :D thanks for the help @Casimir et Hippolyte *guru*, much appreciated!

Comment: I accepted your answer, and thanks again for the perfect answer :D